# List server folders and files php iphone sdk?

Tags: php, ios

I am trying to get a list of folders and files from a server.

*For example*

```
home/user1/files in this you may have home/user1/files/directory1 

home/user1/files/directory2 home/user1/files/photo.xls.
```

And

```
home/user1/files/directory1 you may have home/user1/files/directory1/subdirectory1 
home/user1/files/directory1/subdirectory2 
home/user1/files/directory1/subdirectory2/file.png.
```

I read I can use PHP but how can I present this in an iPhone UI, like an FTP client?

Comment: what's the purpose of doing? Do you want to display this directory structure in your iphone? Do you want to display your server structure or your iPhone directory structure?

Comment: hello i want to display my server directory :)

Comment: hello anyone please :) ?